# React native - assembleDebug - issue - bugsnag

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, bugsnag

i have following issue:

`Execution failed for task ':bugsnag-react-native:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles'. > Collection contains no element matching the predicate.`

If i run ./gradlew assembleDebug --debug i have this:

```
2021-06-04T13:18:14.602+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] Execution worker [Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 4,5,main]] finished, busy: 5.89 secs, idle: 21.451 secs
2021-06-04T13:18:14.604+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph] Timing: Executing the DAG took 27.346 secs
2021-06-04T13:18:14.607+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run tasks'
2021-06-04T13:18:14.607+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Run tasks' completed
2021-06-04T13:18:14.619+0200 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-osx Daemon #0: shutdown
2021-06-04T13:18:14.629+0200 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-osx Daemon #1: shutdown
2021-06-04T13:18:14.631+0200 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-osx Daemon #2: shutdown
2021-06-04T13:18:14.634+0200 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-osx Daemon #3: shutdown
2021-06-04T13:18:14.637+0200 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-osx Daemon #4: shutdown
2021-06-04T13:18:14.639+0200 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-osx Daemon #5: shutdown
2021-06-04T13:18:14.641+0200 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-osx Daemon #6: shutdown
2021-06-04T13:18:14.642+0200 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices] [KOTLIN] Deleted session-is-alive flag file: build/kotlin/sessions/kotlin-compiler-12158603441023875159.salive
2021-06-04T13:18:14.642+0200 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices] [KOTLIN] Disposed KotlinGradleBuildServices
2021-06-04T13:18:14.642+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
2021-06-04T13:18:14.642+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 16: released lock on root.1
2021-06-04T13:18:14.643+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-06-04T13:18:14.643+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2021-06-04T13:18:14.643+0200 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-osx Daemon #7: shutdown
2021-06-04T13:18:14.644+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-06-04T13:18:14.644+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2021-06-04T13:18:14.644+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':bugsnag-react-native:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles'.
2021-06-04T13:18:14.644+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
2021-06-04T13:18:14.644+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-06-04T13:18:14.645+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2021-06-04T13:18:14.645+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2021-06-04T13:18:14.645+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-06-04T13:18:14.645+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

My dependencies are:
`implementation'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0+' implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"]) implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"   implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"`

Build script is:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 29
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
   
}
}
```

I'm on this issue since yesterday and I have no changes the app. Someone can help?

Comment: Do you get the error only when producing a debug APK or it also fails to run. Please provide more details

Comment: i have error in the release when there is the installation step (unsafe operation)

Comment: If the project is public, can you share the github link so we can check the source code.

Comment: thx Yonatan, i can't share the project becouse is not public, i just wrote this issue becouse there is no other than explain the same problem, how i can do?